# i want to read cell data from table and so that i can update in database

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have created a table in react js and now i want to read data of row and post it to database but m not able to read data of cell or row

i have tried a lot still nothing working for me

```
class Table extends Component {
      state = {};
      function = () => {
        var Row = document.getElementById("somerow");
        var Cells = Row.getElementsByTagName("td");
        var Table = document.getElementById("table");
        alert(Cells[0].innerText);
      };
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <html>
              <body>
                <table id="table" >
                  <tr id="somerow" bgcolor="#f5f5f5">
                    <th>Item Code</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <Input type="text" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <Input type="text" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <Input type="number" min="0.01" step="0.01" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <Input type="currency" />

                    </td>

                  </tr>
                </table>
                <Input type="button" name="click" onClick={this.function} 
                  />
```

even after putting value in the cells i get blank result in alert 
and i even have to update these details to database so really need help

Comment: You don't want the `innerText` of the `td` you want the `value` of the `Input` - which is some other react component

Comment: actually i searched and somewhere these steps to get the data i want to get the data of this table and update it to database

Comment: Can you show the code for the `<Input />` component, or is a third party component that you're using?

Comment: this is the whole single code in this file and all components are in this code only no third party apart from that <Input> m using from ant.design

Comment: oh, you should use a lowercase `<input />` then, but if you make them controlled inputs and store the value in state, then it should be easy to use them when you submit. How many rows are likely to be in this table?

Comment: rows are 10 and it will depend on the user how much row he wants to use plz tell me how to read data from table row by row and i want to update the same data to database table

Comment: Try giving this a read https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: it doesn't help me coz i m stuck in tables as i have mentioned above i have table now i want to get the value row by row so that i can later on save that value to database

Comment: The fact that it's in a table shouldn't matter too much, it's more the values and the  relationship of the inputs that are in each row that counts. But I'm afraid I'm not here to write your code for you